# I have two tables containing the following columns

Tags: mysql, query-builder

I have two tables  CandRegistrationTable and CandAttendenceTxn containing the following column name,roll no and candAttendenceTxn contain candidateIdFk reference to candRegistrationTable pkid,is_present,paper_Type. i need select query to show list of name  registered in CandRegistrationTable where is_present is null and paper_Type=value selected from UI(eg paper I,paper II)

Answer (score 0):

Your question got voted down because you have not asked a clear question and have not shown your working clearly at all. Try and show your tables clearly:

**CandRegistrationTable**

```
[name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[roll_no] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[is_present] [varchar](50) NULL,
[candy_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

**CandAttendenceTxn**

```
    [candidateIdFk] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [paper_Type] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [candy_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

then your query can look like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CandRegistrationTable
JOIN table_1 ON CandAttendenceTxn.candidateIdFk = CandRegistrationTable.candidateIdFk
WHERE (table_1.is_present = null AND table_1.paper_Type='$value')
ORDER BY table_1.candy_id
```

I hope it helps.